# Laravel custom guard remember me function not working with AuthenticateUser trait

Tags: laravel

I created a second guard name customer that uses the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait everything seems to work well except the remember me function every time i login i can't seem to log out. So i think the remember me is using the default guard so how do i fix this issue? Can i fix the issue in the login controller?

customer login controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\CustomerAuth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Customer;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
    return Auth()->guard('customer');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        if(Auth::user() || Auth::guard('customer')->user())
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
        else{
            return view('customer-auth.login');
        }
    }





}
```

---

AuthenticateUser.php

```
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a few custom guards. I had to make a new logout method that uses

```
\Auth::guard($guard)->logout();
```

since by default the logout() method in StatefulGuard.php does not accept any parameters like a guard.

Comment: oh ok and that logout method you create it in your logincontroller? @NMahurin

Comment: If you want to. I had to make an authentication handling class that takes care of the grunt work since we have a lot of guards and authenticatable models.